# IBM MQ with SSL offload, receiving back "prot algorithm" bit set in ECapFlags3

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

can anyone clarify what the MQ "Prot Algorithm" bit of the ECapFlags3 struct is for and/or does, and why and when it gets set by IBM MQ during a connection setup?

At a high level, we're implementing an SSL offload configuration for a client (Mulesoft) to connect to an IBM MQ queue via an F5.  Whenever we enable SSL, the connection fails. With TLS off, the data flow works fine.  (it's not something basic, like not sharing an acceptable cipher, etc. - the TLS handshake completes between the Mulesoft client and the F5 fine, and data flows - but the client appears to stop the connection). We don't see any difference in what the F5 sends over to IBM MQ in either case; the only difference we can find is that the IBM MQ replies all have the ECapFlags3 "Prot Algorithm" bit set, when TLS is enabled between the client and the F5.

In performing captures, we note the following:

- With TLS on, the TLS handshake completes apparently without issue, and MQ packets do go over to the IBM MQ
- With TLS on, we see two "INITIAL_DATA" MQ requests go over, and receive responses back; immediately after that, the client sends a TLS alert
- With TLS off, we see the same two INITIAL_DATA messages and responses, then the client sends credentials (i.e., sends a "USERID_DATA" message)
- We see no unexpected differences in the first 2 exchanges (the INITIAL_DATA calls) with or without TLS, except that the MQ reply, to both INITIAL_DATA calls, has the msb of the ECapFlags3 set; this bit is labeled as "Prot Algorithm" by Wireshark

The whole exchange happens within 300ms when successful (no TLS), and within less when TLS is enabled, so no timeout should be occurring.

Our working hypothesis is that the "Prot Algorithm" bit being set is having some effect on the client; correction would involve either preventing it from being set, or adjusting the client configuration to handle it cleanly.

Any information on that flag bit - or any other thoughts! - welcome.  Thank you!

Comment: Is the F5 terminating the TLS session on the MQ Client side and then starting a non-encrypted session to the queue manager?  Does the ca-file contain the signer of the client cert?

Comment: Thx for replying, JoshMC ... no, no bridging - simple offload - the F5 is leaving the connection to MQ entirely unencrypted.  And, when I examine the packet exchange with MQ, they're identical, whether the client SSL profile is in use or not ... right down to the syn/syn-ack/ack level.  The MQ messages that go over are identical as well, as far as I can tell - I quite honestly can't figure out how MQ even "knows" that the TLS offload is in use; but it does consistently send back that ECapFlags3 "Prot Algorithm" bit as soon as I turn the TLS to/from the client back on, on the F5 VIP.

Comment: What error do your see in the queue manager log?  What error does the client see?  Does the ca-file on the F5 client-ssl profile contain the signer of the client cert?

Comment: Still trying to get the queue manager logs - stovepipes. On the client side, the error (with some vals masked with Xs) is:

com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'XXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'XXXX.com(1418)'.

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').

Comment: (cont) ...  

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'XX(1418)' rejected.  
 [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2009],3=XX(1418),5=RemoteConnection.asyncConnectionBroken]  

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009  

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'XX/XX:1418 (XX)'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=XX/XX:1418 (XX),4=TCP]

Comment: To answer your other questions - we're not using a client certificate, so the F5's client SSL profile doesn't specify any CA file.  And again, the TLS handshake completes, and the F5 proxies the plaintext MQ msgs to the IBM MQ listener successfully.

Comment: Is the client sending a password? My theory is that Prot Algorithm is in reference to the password protection algorithm.  When MQ higher than 8.0 makes a connection one of the things negotiated is the password protection algorithm.   If the connection is over a non-NULL cipher TLS session it does not use the password protection algorithm since the TLS cipher is stronger than the password protection algorithm.  My guess is that since the client is using TLS it does not negotiate a password protection algorithm but the queue manager sees it is not TLS and requires one.

Comment: Try doing end to end TLS to see if that goes away. Try playing around with disabling enforcement of the password protection algorithm being required on the queue manager (qm.ini) and/or client (mqclient.ini). Note the only two options are none (null) or real (3DES). This is all hidden from you and is negotiated based on TLS non-NULL cipher or not.   I suspect that you have hit a unexpected situation where the client doesn't think it is required but the queue manager does.

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - hampered by lack of expertise/support on the MQ side, so punching in the dark a bit, and def can't flip on TLS on their end.  We've figured out that the MQ client code is checking if there's a TLS cipherspec specified (which as far as we can tell is mandatory in order to use TLS), and if there is, separately _also_ encrypting the channel credentials (userid/pw) - which we think is bollixing everything up.  But we haven't been able to find a way to suppress that behavior in the client (which is a Mulesoft adaptor, but using the IBM-provided Java MQ libs, i think).

Comment: Have the mule app try this setting `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=N`.  My guess is the server is set to require password protection which the MQ Client does either by a non-NULL cipher or with the pw protection algorithm.  If it sees the cipher it won't use the algorithm.   By connecting without TLS and settings the above java system property it should also fail.  If you specify a NULL cipher without the above java system property it should work since it would be protected by the algorithm.